# Online Software Tracking Software

Tags: php, version-control, software-distribution

I am looking for a good development tool that will help me track revisions of software I am creating, and that is web based. Just looking for suggestions on what others use.

And not one that is hosted through another solution but that I can host myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://github.com/ (git), http://bitbucket.org/ (mercurial/git)

Answer (score 4):

The best one (that you can host yourself) would be: **[Atlassian FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/)** (which includes [source browsing features](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview/source-browser))

[image: revisions list]

Not free, but you can have [up to ten users with 10$](http://www.atlassian.com/starter/) (or even [free for open-source project](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/pricing.jsp)).

Works with Subversion, Git, CVS, Perforce, ClearCase, and Mercurial repositories.