# git: repo monitoring tool

Tags: git, scripting, githooks

Do you know any good repo monitoring solution?

I'd like to get information when someone pushes to remote repo (preferably via taskbar tray icon: "someuser pushed…").

Other solutions I consider:

- recieve hook
- periodically git log via cron
- check for updates on running every git command

(my system of choice is Ubuntu)

Comment: Do you want to write it yourself or are you looking for existing implementations?

Comment: I have found `zenity` which displays taskbar notifications, but now I need some smart and lightweight git commands to check for updates.

Comment: @mizipzor Im looking for the best solution. I do not know any existing implementations yet. I'm asking your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pushing (through a git hook) is not convenient, then a polling system is easy to setup:

A simple **[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)** job could poll your Git repo for new information and send an email or do any other task of your choice.
It has various tray tracker like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/hudson-tray-tracker/).

Or a [code browsing tool like FishEye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077772/online-software-tracking-software/3078611#3078611) can equally poll for new data and present them in a nice web interface.

Both tools are built to talk to Git repositories (as well as other: SVN, ClearCase, ...)

Comment: I think the best way would be to use the hooks and then just push the info off somewhere. Options where or what that somewhere is is pretty much are pretty much limitless from here on.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [git-commit-notifier](http://github.com/wesabe/git-commit-notifier) which sends nice looking emails for each push.

Since it sends mail, you need an SMTP server. If you dont have one yourself you can [use Gmails](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server). I assume you already have an email address and some nifty tray program to display incoming emails.

Havent tried it myself but as far as push notifications go, it seems to do what you want.