# Is good idea to use gerrit to host the git repository instead of gitolite or gitosis?

Tags: git, gitosis, gitorious, gitolite, gerrit

Originally I try to use gitosis to manage the git repositories in the company, and later notice gitolite is kind of enhancement of gitosis.

And also I heard gerrit could be used for the same purpose, but from the description, gerrit is mainly used for code review.

So which is the best way for setting up git server

- using gitolite (for git repo) **AND** gerrit (for code review) together
- using gerrit **ONLY** to manage git repository and codereview

Can you give some suggestion ?

BTW: http://gitorious.org/ is considered in the future

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're going to use gerrit at all, you might as well use it for hosting as well as code review -- the workflow is easier that way, as gerrit will manage merging your reviewed code into its repository, and that's what you want to be publishing -- if you host elsewhere, you're going to have to either set up a method for automatically pulling from gerrit or you're going to have a way for your developers to bypass the code review by pushing their changes straight to the hosted repositories and ignoring gerrit altogether.

Recent versions of gerrit can integrate gitweb, giving you the nice web interface to browse with, but protected by the ACLs you've set up.

Comment: The Qt Project uses gitorious as the repository and gerrit for code review... They have it separated and all works very nice. I personally would separate the repository from code review... In the case of Qt, you push and pull from gerrit but it actually works with the gitorious repositories... Here you can find a diagram of how it works: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Code_Reviews

Answer (score 3):

I use only **gitolite** for the fine-grained ACL it provides.

For the code-review part, I use [FishEye](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077772/online-software-tracking-software/3078611#3078611) (not free even though free licenses exist for certain projects) and Crucible (both from Atlassian).

That allows me to separate the two features (ACL vs. Code review) on two separate servers.

Comment: Vonc, could you please configure my gerrit (which is up and running) with your gitolite setup please ?

Comment: @Gilles: I will, on Tuesday ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gerrit if you need code review, it has its own ssh server that integrate git.

Gerrit use user groups and allow you to specify permissions at desire level, it also have some features to accept contribution from external developers easily, you can force developers to accept some TOS.